# exporting formats from python pandas dataframe to excel format

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to convert two columns

example

```
col_a               col_b
07/30/2017 0:00     35.95
```

I want to export it as

```
col_a               col_b
July-30-17          $35.95
```

Edit:  I was trying some excel outputs like

```
money_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '$#,##0', 'bold': True})
worksheet.set_column('G:K', 12, money_fmt)
```

Comment: The data are already in the required form. The formatting you require will have to be applied to the spreadsheet somehow. The most likely useful module is `openpyxl`.

Comment: I was thinking something like this could work.  money_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '$#,##0', 'bold': True})